# How to get all the content inside a div including script and style tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, editor

I am going to make a HTML compiler/Code Executor. User can edit the code of the HTML page , then user will click on the run button and then the code will run on the second section/div.

All the code is executing normally, but it skips the `<script>` and `<style>` tag and all code inside these tag.

**The Javascript Code is :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runcode()
        {
         var code = $('#source_code').text();
         $('#code_execute').html(code);
        }
</script>
```

This is the screen shot of the Editor:

Please check the screenshot of editor first.

[image: Screenshot]

Output of the **`var code = $('#source_code').text();`**

```
<html><head><title>HTML Style Attribute Using Class</title><style></style></head><body><div class="container">I am a div ,Class container applied one me . </div></body></html>
```

Please help me , Why this  content is ignoring .

Comment: probably you will need an iframe

Comment: Explain , How i can use the iframe to meet the problem

Comment: Did you try `.html()` instead of `.text()` ?  `.text()` will only get the text, *excluding* any tags etc

Comment: Yes i tried the html() ,val() both . Both html() and text() are not working. html() has empty results.

Comment: `.html()` works fine for getting script content: https://jsfiddle.net/2mv8tz6s/  Your "screenshot" doesn't include a script tag or div with `id="source_code".  Please include all relevant information in your question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and especially [ask].  If you have some specific code to be looked at, please include a [mcve] - with emphasis on the *complete* example.

Comment: The recent edit shows the hidden html.  It's not possible to get that html using `.text()`.  Therefore your question is incomplete / inconsistent.  Please consider updating it.

Comment: you can user .html() this may help yours : http://jsfiddle.net/UBw44/